# R split string and populate fields in dataframe (have tried everything)

Tags: r, string, split

Easiest way to split `BeforeSplit` and populate the last 3 columns in my data frame.

I have tried `sub`, `gsub`, `str_split_fixed`, `strsplit`.  I am having no luck.  There is a space between each word in `BeforeSplit`.

Thank you!

data in data frame:

```
BeforeSplit             NetID   FName   LName

dduck Donald Duck       dduck   Donald  Duck
mmouse Mickey mmouse   mmouse   Mickey  Mouse
```

Comment: is `BeforeSplit` in a file, data frame, list, or a string?

Comment: It's helpful to be able to see what you've tried that didn't work so we can help figure out *why* and know what is & isn't covered by "everything." [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making a question that's easier to help with